# Controllers relations to Mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How does a mailer have access to the instance variables of a controller?

For example how does the mailer have access to an `@user` from the `users_controller`?

Would the `users_controller` need to call the `mailer` for the `mailer` to be provided access to the controllers variable?

I'm just extremely confused on the relation `mailers` have to `controllers`, i.e.

1) How a controller can access/call a mailer.
2) How a mailer has access to a controllers instance variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mailer is just a class that inherits from ActionMailer, much like controllers inherit from ApplicationController. From a controller, you call the appropriate mailer and pass it in the variables the mailer needs to send the message. See [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer) for the example I used and more information.

> How does a mailer have access to the instance variables of a
>   controller?

The variables are passed in. In the following example from the controller, the @user variable is passed in:

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
```

> Would the users_controller need to call the mailer for the mailer to
>   be provided access to the controllers variable?

Yes.

Comment: So to make sure I understand correctly the controller accesses the mailer, not the other way around.  But how does the controller have access to the mailer?  How is the controller able to call the mailer?  Can any controller access the UserMailer, or only the users_controller?

Comment: Yes, the controller calls the mailer, not the other way around. Rails automatically handles granting the controllers access to the mailers. Any controller can access the UserMailer.

Answer (score 1):

Mailer should not have access to the controller, they should not even know that a controller exists.

The controller just give the needed objects as parameters.

You can see this in the official Guide [Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), section "2.1.4 Calling the Mailer"